# Parallel manipulation of object with python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a list of ojects `ObjList` where all objects are instances of the same class. This class has a method `run` which I would like to execute in parallel for the objects in `ObjList`.

The results of the computation are then stored inside the objects. Without parallelisation I currently do something like

```
for obj in self.ObjList:
    obj.Run()
```

This coded is part of class method of a class which contains and handles "lists" of these objects. Afterwards, I want to be able to read the results of the computations performed by `obj.Run`. I tried the `multiprocessing.Pool` methods where I ran into problems with `pickle`. I also tried to use `multiprocessing.Process` but there I had the problem that the results were stored in a copy of the object which then was discarded. I did not manage to return the manipulated object.

Is there a simple way of applying the same class method to a list of objects which are instances of the same class (which is rather complex and uses multiple objects itself)?

**Edit**: I tried the approach suggested in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239695/parallel-execution-of-class-methods) but then I always receive errors of the form

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'someclass.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallel execution of class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239695/parallel-execution-of-class-methods)

Comment: @JacquesGaudin: I tried this approach but then I am running into problems with `pickle`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that what I will offer is a "simple way", but see if this works for you.

I would recommend using a third party component (like [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)) to transform your code to a compiled machine code that “just-in-time” when needed to 
utilize the power of some parallel architecture, like the [NVIDIA GPUs](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python) or your own multi-core CPU. That way you won't need to handle the hassle of the parallel optimization.

As each code/application has it's own logic and flow, I can't specify the exact transformation of your code, but this is a good line, in my opinion, to follow, that (hopefully) doesn't require much alterations to your code.

Comment: Answers that are only a link are rarely the most helpful. Links have a tendency to die, so people looking for help on the same problem in the future might get nothing out of it. Please summarize what the OP should do based on the resources you link in addition to providing the link.

Comment: Sure. I made the changes, hope it's up to par. As a side note, I added links to a very solid web pages that the probability of them dying is lesser than the probability of this web page dying, with your comment to (and) my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose to use this code snippet first.

```
def thread_run(obj):
    obj.Run()

def Dothejob():
    tr = []
    for cmd in obj:
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread_run, args=(obj))
        t.start()
        tr.append(t) 
    # waiting for all threads ended
    for item in tr:
        item.join()

Dothejob()
```